# Did Regina rape Graham?

Tags: once-upon-a-time, morality

One of the creators of the TV series [*Once Upon a Time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time_(TV_series)) seems to suggest that [Regina didn't rape Graham](https://twitter.com/wiccagirl24/status/310191605032316929). I know the creators have the final say over what the characters intended, thought and did, but they can’t just change the definition of rape.

It’s been well over 2 years since the Twitter conversation occurred. I guess they couldn’t say much to avoid spoilers or something (even though Graham was died in a 2011 or 2012 episode if I recall correctly).

So what's the verdict? Did Regina rape Graham or not? It doesn't seem to be resolved in the twitter conversation. Might there be any **new** information from the show or the creators that sheds some light as to whether or not Regina raped Graham?

Comment: It seems you already have your answer in that very Twitter feed. Adam and Eddie confirmed that she did not use Graham's heart to force him into sex. On the other hand, she erased his memories and added new ones to make him into her lover. That was nonconsensual, thus rape. Even worse, she arguably did the same thing to many other people in Storybrooke. Regina almost certainly would not have seen it as such, but that does not change things. Had Graham managed to survive long enough to see the curse broken, he certainly would have disagreed.

Comment: That whole situation can be seen as an essential part of Regina's Season 1 delusion. She believed that she could cast a Dark curse in order to ensure her happiness, and thereafter be an ordinary, kind person. But the curse itself was an act of supreme evil, ripping people away from their homes, altering their minds, and placing them in a position they never would have agreed to (not to mention the price). Worse, they were not even truly happy. There's a reason the spell was called a curse.

Comment: I know less than nothing about this thing people are calling twitter. :)

Comment: @RedCaio neither do I :)) Did you really have to delete your answer though?

Comment: @Jonah but A&E don't seem to think Regina raped Graham. Do they?

Comment: @Jonah people probably would've kept downvoting :( But I stand by everything I said in my answer.

Comment: RedCaio's answer seemed to indicate that A&E didn't think so at first, but later reconsidered. BTW, I upvoted, because even when it is impossible to satisfy the requirements of a question as written, an answer may still be helpful.

Comment: I guess I could un-delete my answer and edit it a bit. I just hope people are nice and don't downvote. [ [hides under the covers](http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/2014-03/enhanced/webdr07/18/17/enhanced-29045-1395177838-7.jpg)]

Comment: I think it also depends on how you look at the dual personalities.  Regina created new people in a way. You could say that Graham was her willing partner, the Huntsman was not.  She raped the Huntsman, but did not rape Graham.  But if you don't see it that way and she did rape Graham, then she also orchestrated the rape of other people, by partnering them with people they otherwise would not have been partnered with.

Comment: @BekahEvieBel I was thinking the latter part but the former part. Brilliant insight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some searching around, **there doesn't seem to be any *new* information on this subject from the creators of *Once Upon A Time*.** It is possible that they simply wanted to avoid giving attention to the issue.

It is true that, at one point, writer Adam Horowitz [said it was not rape](https://twitter.com/AdamHorowitzLA/status/310191844195708928):

> she didn't use his heart for that. I know. Trust me.

However, Horowitz has also [contradicted](https://twitter.com/AdamHorowitzLA/status/310125352947175424) that, saying instead that Regina *did* rape Graham:

> @MdMeiriona: So, once again I'm going to ask. When are you going to stop joking and address the fact Regina raped Graham.
>
> @AdamHorowitzLA: She **also** killed him, which we addressed. Neither thing's a joke. Regina has done terrible things which is why she is the Evil Queen.

Notice that Horowitz says "also", as in "in addition to". In other words, he's saying, "In addition to raping him, she also killed him; she is evil."

@Jonah makes some good points in his comment.

> She erased his memories and added new ones to make him into her lover. That was nonconsensual, thus rape. (...) Had Graham managed to survive long enough to see the curse broken, he certainly would have disagreed [with her actions].

It should also be pointed out that, in the farytale world, the evil queen did rape the huntsman.

From a *Once Upon A Time* [forum post](http://forums.onceuponatimefansite.com/viewtopic.php?t=1643):

> On the other hand, the Huntsman was most definitely raped. The Queen took his heart, then kissed him, then said she could kill him at any time, and that he was now her pet, and asked for him to be sent to his chambers. Since it was doing it or dying, it's definitely rape, as the definition includes coercion.

**Unless someone gets the creators of *Once Upon A Time* to shed new light on this issue, this is probably the only answer you're going to get.**

Comment: I've downvoted. The OP is explictly looking for info that's more recent than the twitter link they already posted in their question.

Comment: @Richard and RedCaio, thanks. I edited my question. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: RedCaio, I wasn't notified about the edit, but anyway are you sure you are taking into account that [this](https://twitter.com/AdamHorowitzLA/status/310191844195708928) came after [this](https://twitter.com/AdamHorowitzLA/status/310125352947175424)?

Comment: @Richard thanks for clarifying that for me (basically I know less than nothing about this thing people call twitter). Anyway, I've updated my answer to fit what the question is asking (and the OP even accepted it), so I just wanted to let you know in case you wanted to un-downvote and/or upvote. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @redcaio - The edit certainly merits the removal of my downvote since it now addresses the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, my view on this is that what the creators meant is that Regina didn't *further* rape Graham, like [conditioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) on the curse, Regina didn't rape Graham. However, Regina, [unconditionally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability), did rape Graham. Something like Storybrooke Graham consented to have sex with Regina to the extent of free will and knowledge that Storybrooke Graham had, but well of course the identity of 'Storybrooke Graham' is part of Regina's manipulation and so any sex he has with her is like nonconsensual...

Additionally, it's like any sex that the characters have, whether or not Regina is involved in the sex, is like rape by Regina but in an indirect kind of way. I think of this as like a fraudulent - instead of forceful - indirect version/analogue of some kind of forceful indirect rape like person A deceives (for fraudulent) or forces (for forceful) persons B and C to have sex.